# Why does Get-Winevent in parallel workflow wants to use PSRemoting?

Tags: powershell, powershell-v4.0

I'm building a wrapper script for Get-Winevent to search multiple computers' event logs in parallel, using multiple search criteria.

I'm contructing a XML filter for Get-Winevent, then call this fairly simple workflow:

```
WorkFlow Get-ParallelEvent {

    Param(
        [string[]]$Computers,
        [string]$FilterXml
    )

    #Query computers
    ForEach -Parallel ($Computer in $Computers) {
            If (Test-Connection $Computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
                Get-WinEvent -ComputerName  $Computer -FilterXml $FilterXml -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            }
    }
}
```

But when I run the script, I get the error:

> Could not find a parameter named 'ComputerName'. Remote connectivity in this command is handled by the 'PSComputerName' parameter.

However, I don't want to depend on PSRemoting (which is not enabled on all our servers), and Get-Winevent absolutely does support querying remote systems without resorting to PSRemoting.

After much trial and error I added a dummy ForEach-loop with just one iteration, using a variable that doesn't affect execution. That works as intended - PSRemoting is not required (I can use -ComputerName rather than -PSComputerName):

```
WorkFlow Get-ParallelEvent {

    Param(
        [string[]]$Computers,
        [string]$FilterXml
    )

    #Query computers
    @('dummy') | ForEach {
        ForEach -Parallel ($Computer in $Computers) {
            If (Test-Connection $Computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
                Get-WinEvent -ComputerName  $Computer -FilterXml $FilterXml -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This shouldn't cause any overhead, so I can live with this fix. However, I'm very curious as to why Get-Winevent requires the use of PSRemoting in the original workflow, and why that changes by nesting the same code in a ForEach-loop.

Thanks.